# Referencing for an on click event for 150 images that are named the same but have numbers after them

Tags: javascript, html, image, interpolation

Hello so i have a fetch for a pokedex that i'm looking to reference each of the images in the pokedex for an on click event,

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png]

the 1 before png goes from 1-150 for all the pokemon from my fetch so is there a way to interpolation it like `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${i}.png"`

and making a for loop i want to be able to click the pictures and it bring up the stats of pokemon i have all that info ready to reference i just need to be able to get the pictures as their own id for click events

Comment: can you share any attempt you have done so far in code?

Comment: Gotta catch em all

Comment: oh sorry about that guys i didn't see all your comments yes so i just made each picture an id for an onclick event

Comment: const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
    const pokemonli = pokemon.map ( 
        (pokelist) => `<li class="pictures" onclick="selectPokemon(${pokelist.id})">
        <img class="pokeImage" src="${pokelist.image}"/></li>` 
        ).join('');

    pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonli;
};

const selectPokemon = async (id) => {
    // console.log(id)
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const pokelist = await response.json()
    displayPopup(pokelist)
}

Comment: i have referenced the pokelist earlier to just fetch image and id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
document.getElementById("placehere").innerHTML = Array.from({length: 10},  // change to whatever number
    (_, i) => `<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${i+1}.png"/>`)
  .join("")
```

```html
<div id="placehere"></div>
```

Older answers

```js
const pokemons = [
  {name:"bla1", id:1},
  {name:"bla2", id:2}
];

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pokemons.map(pokemon => `<a href="/${pokemon.name}.html"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png"></a>`).join("")
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Or

```js
const pokemons = [{name:"bla1"},{name:"bla2"}];

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pokemons.map((pokemon,i) => `<a href="/${pokemon.name}.html"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${i+1}.png"></a>`).join("")
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: YES thankyou i will have to work on it i didn't think of using pokemon.id thankyou!

Comment: See updated code. Much better to only update the DOM once